# how do i animate with tailwind css in my next.js project?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations, tailwind-css

So i have three images , i wwant them to all go in circle after each other . I am using tailwind css for my styling . I found the circular path the images have to follow and also the keyframe style . How do i config this style in my tailwind config file and use it in my project

HERE IS THE HTML AND CSS SAMPLE CODE FOR WHAT I AM TYRYING TO ACHIEVE FOR EACH IMAGES . CODEPEN LINK https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/zEpLpK

**HTML**

```
<svg viewbox="0,0 10,10" width="200px" height="200px">
  
  <!-- the path to be animated along -->  
  
  
  <!-- the mover -->
  <circle class="marker" r="1" fill="orange"></circle>
  
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.track {
  stroke: #ccc;
}

.marker {
  motion-path: path('M 5 5 m -4, 0 a 4,4 0 1,0 8,0 a 4,4 0 1,0 -8,0');
  offset-path: path('M 5 5 m -4, 0 a 4,4 0 1,0 8,0 a 4,4 0 1,0 -8,0');
  animation: move 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  100% { 
    motion-offset: 100%;
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}
```

BELOW IS MY NEXT.JS CODE , WHERE I AM TRYING TO INPUT THE STYLE ABOVE

```
<div className="bg-landingPage h-screen">
                {/* ROTATING CLOTHES  & TEXTS*/}
                <div>
                    {/* CLOTHES */}
                    <div>
                       <div style= " ">
                           
                        <Image
                        width={400}
                        height={300}
                        src="/img/travis/rot1.png"
                        />
                       </div>
                        
                        <Image
                        width={400}
                        height={300}
                        src="/img/fearOfGod/rot2.png"
                        />
                        
                        
                         <Image
                        width={350}
                        height={300}
                        src="/img/travis/rot.png"
                        />


                    </div>
                    {/* TEXTS */}
                    <div>

                    </div>

                </div>

                {/* SLIDE-SHOW OF CLOTHES */}
                <div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

**HERE IS MY TAILWIND CONFIG FILE**

```
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  purge: [ 
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        navbar: "#1D1F20",
        landingPage : "#034335"
      },
      textColor:{
        "navbar":"#D49F6A"
      },
      Animation:{
        
      }
     
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("@tailwindcss/line-clamp")],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need tailwind to do this, just add those classes to your CSS file and use it in the element you want to animate.

The tailwind config file is for theme customization, if you need to create custom classes just add it to your CSS file.